# Ringing at input of digital isolator while driving a mosfet with high voltage and current

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, powermosfet, digital-isolator

From a rectified main 230V supply + 4x120µF 400V capacitor, I'm driving a [STW40N65M2](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2816088.pdf) mosfet which commutes a big coil.

Gate is driven by [MCP14A0304T](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP14A0303_4_5-Data-Sheet-20006046A.pdf). Gate current is limited by a 30.9 Ohm resistor. Gate driver is powered
by a 15V external AC/DC converter. This converter shares GND with HV circuit.
The gate driver is fed by a [iso7730DBQ](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=26&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fiso7730) (powered by the external 15v converter and an LDO)
There's a freewheel diode [PSDF3060L1_T0_00001](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/1057/PSDF3060L1-2327152.pdf).

I don't have the exact caracteristics of the coil but diameter is around 25 cm (10 inches), length 2,5cm (1 inch)
and roughly 200-300 rounds. It's resistance is around 22 ohms.

The (isolator - gate driver - mos gate) chain is driven by a pwm signal from a microcontroler.

Here are some schematics. Please, consider that output of a schematic goes to input of the next one whatever its name ("A", "C" or nothing).

Isolator:
[image: Isolator]

Gate driver:
[image: Gate driver]

Mos and coil:
[image: mos and coil]

For the whole picture, result is pretty much what I need:

- Blue : coil currrent
- yellow : pwm at input of isolator
- orange : Vgs measured with DP1007 differential probe.

[image]

But zooming to a single pwm pulse shows some ringing on gate **and on the input of the isolator:**

My questions are:

1. Ringing went smaller by increasing the resistor but is there another way to limit ringing? Btw the screenshot shows an already inscreased R.
2. How this ringing can be propagated to the input of the isolator which by definition is... isolated.... It's a concern because voltage peak reaches ~4.5V not far from microcontroler limit. Can it be a measurement error? If no, what is the relevant fix?

[image]

Comment: Try connecting (shorting) both leads of your diff probe together to the signal to see if the "ringing" is actually common-mode noise, i.e. it may not be real.

Comment: Not sure whether the test should be done with other probes connected to the system or not. I tried with nothing connected and I can't see anything.

Comment: Are you sure that R8 should be 30.9 Ohm ? Datasheet "test" specify 4.7 Ohm ...

Comment: Well, I wanted to limit the gate current to fit my driver and thought that it would make in the same time make an RC filter that will help with ringin